# Ngnix/Wordpress seamless redirect subfolder to subdirectory with proxy-pass

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I have two servers for one domain

- server A hosting mywebsite.com and
- server B hosting blog.mywebsite.com (Blog WordPress).

My goal is to have a seamless url for my blog with: http://mywebsite.com/test23 with the content of server B.

My first redirection is working (location /test23). I can get my home page and get other pages but I am not able to connect to my WP admin. I am getting a 404 on mywebsite.com/test23/wp-login.php.

*Server A nginx conf file*

```
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mywebsite.com;

     location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
             include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
     }         

      location /test23 {
             rewrite ^/test23(.*) /$1 break;
              proxy_pass http://blog.mywebsite.com/;
     }

      location /test23/wp-admin {
             rewrite ^/test23/wp-admin(.*) /$1 break;
             proxy_pass http://blog.mywebsite.com/wp-admin;
     }
```

I guess I need to manage exclusion of the wp-admin folder? I m kind of lost :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you proxy the "/test23" path and you use a rewrite rule to bind anything using that adress you don' need the second location block.

Try using this:

```
location /test23 {
             rewrite ^/test23(/.*)$ /$1 break;
              proxy_pass http://blog.mywebsite.com/;
     }
```

If you haven't set proxy rules , this block may also look like:

```
location /test23 {
                 rewrite ^/test23(/.*)$ /$1 break;
                 proxy_pass http://blog.mywebsite.com/;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                 proxy_redirect    off;
    }
```

You should use a backslash after"test23" in the rewrite. In the first case it works because there is nothing after /test23 in the request.

In the second request it gets mixed up because the position of the location blocks matters. So it gets rewritten by the first rule, which leads to an error without the backslash.